# Usage of generic classes

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to understand generics via Java but I have some questions that is on my mind.

For example, let's think about the *priority queue* ADT. We can represent this ADT by an interface, which we can call `MyPriorityQueue`. Now, if I am not wrong, every element that we will put in a priority queue must have two components, namely the "priority value" and the "value".

We can create a type called `Entry` to represent the entries that will be put in a priority queue. Since the priority values and values can be of any type, if I am not wrong the `Entry` class should be generic.

Now, back to the priority queue ADT, if I want to implement the `MyPriorityQueue` interface with a class named, say `MyPQ`, since *every* priority queue's elements must be `Entries`, should `MyPQ` be generic or not?

From this point of view, it looks like should not because it will support only one type of element, which is `Entry` but on the other hand, it looks like it should be generic. Because, say two types of `MyPQ` instances, first is a to do list named `toDoList` and second is an airport boarding queue named `boardingQueue` should not be allowed to have one instance's `Entries` in another, meaning that one should not be allowed to attempt to put an `Entry` of the `boardingQueue` to the `toDoList` and vice versa.

This suggests that `MyPQ` *should* be generic. Also should `MyPriorityQueue` interface be generic or not? If yes, why so?

I know this has been a kind of long text but I would very much appreciate it if you could explain this to me.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here - `PriorityQueue` is a class, not an interface.

Comment: Well, sorry it's my bad. I wasn't aware of a built in PriorityQueue class so I will adjust my question right now.

Comment: May I ask what that value is supposed to be?
Is it fixed or can it be multiple different types? That basically answers if your base class should be generic or not.

Comment: For example, if one will create an instace of MyPQ for implementing a to do list, the value might be a type called "Task". Or if one will create an instance of MyPQ for implementing an airport boarding queue, the value might be a type called "AirTraveler"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you HAVE TO make `MyPQ` generic; you will run into compiler issues if you don't. Remember that `Entry` is generic, so its declaration will look something like:

```
public class Entry<K, V> {}
```

Then, your `MyPQ` class will use your `Entry` class, forcing it to be generic, like this:

```
public class MyPQ<K, V> implements MyPriorityQueue<K, V> {

    @Override
    public void add(Entry<K, V> entry){}
}
```

If you don't declare `MyPQ` as generic, then what do you replace `K` and `V` with in `add(Entry<K, V> entry)`? So you get a compile error.


As far as the `MyPriorityQueue` interface goes, you will also have to make it generic, since in there you will probably have methods with generic arguments that implementations will have to override, like `public void add(Entry<K, V> entry);`.

Comment: I see. What if the Entry class is like Entry<K,V> since both priority values and values in an entry can be generic?

Comment: @Utku That's fine. The same rules apply. I have adjusted my answer to that.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the MyPriorityQueue interface? (I have just edited my question from PriorityQueue to MyPriorityQueue) Should it be generic or not? If yes, why so?

Comment: What kind of methods will you put in that interface?

Comment: Default priority queue methods, which can be called enqueue, dequeue, getHighestPriority etc.

Comment: @Utku What will you pass into `enqueue` for example?

Comment: An element specific to the type of instanced MyPQ. For example if I have implemented a to do list with MyPQ, what will be passed into enqueue is an Entry which might have a type "Importance" as priority value and a type "Task" as the value.

Comment: @Utku Which means that in the interface you will have `public void enqueue(K key, V value);`. Look at that! Another `K` and another `V`! Well, I guess the interface has to be generic too.

Comment: @Utku Yeah, generics can be confusing at the beginning. With time and practice, you start seeing things clearly on how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `PriorityQueue`, you'll see a good implementation. It's generic, but requires `Comparable` (or a `Comparator`) objects in it. Priority comes directly from the comparison and there's no need for a special Entry object.

You could recreate this in a more academic way, but it would be worthless to have an Entry class when it's not needed (unlike `Map.Entry`).

Comment: I see. So PriorityQueue interface should be generic because we need to put elements that we can compare their values but the problem of mixing up the elements of toDoList and boardingQueue still persists. What is a correct implementation on that?

Comment: Sorry, `PriorityQueue` is a concrete Java class, I was basing my answer on that.